# What is "Linux Cert Store Sync" when installing "mono" package in my Linux?

Tags: tls, linux, package-manager

While installing some package in my Arch Linux system, I noticed certificates import operation that added 157 new CAs, that is strange for me:

> Synchronize local certs with certs from local Linux trust store.

What are these certificates and why do I need them? Why `mono` package imports them and from **where** (it says, "local Linux trust store")?

Here is the log with certificate names from `pacman -S` output.

```
:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
:: Retrieving packages...
 mono-4.6.1.3-1-x86_64      8.3 MiB  94.6K/s 01:29 [######################] 100%
 keepass-2.34-1-any      1220.1 KiB  81.8K/s 00:15 [######################] 100%
(4/4) checking keys in keyring                     [######################] 100%
(4/4) checking package integrity                   [######################] 100%
(4/4) loading package files                        [######################] 100%
(4/4) checking for file conflicts                  [######################] 100%
(4/4) checking available disk space                [######################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/4) installing libgdiplus                        [######################] 100%
(2/4) installing mono                              [######################] 100%
Linux Cert Store Sync - version 4.6.1.0
Synchronize local certs with certs from local Linux trust store.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

I already trust 0, your new list has 157
Certificate added: CN=ACCVRAIZ1, OU=PKIACCV, O=ACCV, C=ES
Certificate added: CN=ACEDICOM Root, OU=PKI, O=EDICOM, C=ES
Certificate added: C=IT, L=Milan, O=Actalis S.p.A./03358520967, CN=Actalis Authentication Root CA
Certificate added: C=SE, O=AddTrust AB, OU=AddTrust External TTP Network, CN=AddTrust External CA Root
Certificate added: C=SE, O=AddTrust AB, OU=AddTrust TTP Network, CN=AddTrust Class 1 CA Root
Certificate added: C=SE, O=AddTrust AB, OU=AddTrust TTP Network, CN=AddTrust Public CA Root
Certificate added: C=SE, O=AddTrust AB, OU=AddTrust TTP Network, CN=AddTrust Qualified CA Root
Certificate added: C=US, O=AffirmTrust, CN=AffirmTrust Commercial
Certificate added: C=US, O=AffirmTrust, CN=AffirmTrust Networking
Certificate added: C=US, O=AffirmTrust, CN=AffirmTrust Premium
Certificate added: C=US, O=AffirmTrust, CN=AffirmTrust Premium ECC
Certificate added: C=JP, O=Japanese Government, OU=ApplicationCA
Certificate added: CN=Atos TrustedRoot 2011, O=Atos, C=DE
Certificate added: C=ES, CN=Autoridad de Certificacion Firmaprofesional CIF A62634068
Certificate added: C=IE, O=Baltimore, OU=CyberTrust, CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root
Certificate added: C=NO, O=Buypass AS-983163327, CN=Buypass Class 2 CA 1
Certificate added: C=NO, O=Buypass AS-983163327, CN=Buypass Class 2 Root CA
Certificate added: C=NO, O=Buypass AS-983163327, CN=Buypass Class 3 Root CA
Certificate added: C=SK, L=Bratislava, O=Disig a.s., CN=CA Disig Root R1
Certificate added: C=SK, L=Bratislava, O=Disig a.s., CN=CA Disig Root R2
Certificate added: C=CN, O=WoSign CA Limited, CN=CA WoSign ECC Root
Certificate added: C=CN, O=China Financial Certification Authority, CN=CFCA EV ROOT
Certificate added: C=CN, O=CNNIC, CN=CNNIC ROOT
Certificate added: C=GB, S=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=COMODO CA Limited, CN=COMODO Certification Authority
Certificate added: C=GB, S=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=COMODO CA Limited, CN=COMODO ECC Certification Authority
Certificate added: C=GB, S=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=COMODO CA Limited, CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
Certificate added: C=EU, O=AC Camerfirma SA CIF A82743287, OU=http://www.chambersign.org, CN=Chambers of Commerce Root
Certificate added: C=EU, O=AC Camerfirma SA CIF A82743287, OU=http://www.chambersign.org, CN=Global Chambersign Root
Certificate added: C=CN, O=WoSign CA Limited, CN=Certification Authority of WoSign G2
Certificate added: C=FR, O=Dhimyotis, CN=Certigna
Certificate added: C=FR, O=Certinomis, OU=0002 433998903, CN=Certinomis - Autorité Racine
Certificate added: C=FR, O=Certinomis, OU=0002 433998903, CN=Certinomis - Root CA
Certificate added: C=FR, O=Certplus, CN=Class 2 Primary CA
Certificate added: C=FR, O=Certplus, CN=Certplus Root CA G1
Certificate added: C=FR, O=Certplus, CN=Certplus Root CA G2
Certificate added: C=PL, O=Unizeto Sp. z o.o., CN=Certum CA
Certificate added: C=PL, O=Unizeto Technologies S.A., OU=Certum Certification Authority, CN=Certum Trusted Network CA
Certificate added: C=PL, O=Unizeto Technologies S.A., OU=Certum Certification Authority, CN=Certum Trusted Network CA 2
Certificate added: C=EU, L=Madrid (see current address at www.camerfirma.com/address), OID.2.5.4.5=A82743287, O=AC Camerfirma S.A., CN=Chambers of Commerce Root - 2008
Certificate added: C=CN, O=China Internet Network Information Center, CN=China Internet Network Information Center EV Certificates Root
Certificate added: C=GB, S=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=Comodo CA Limited, CN=AAA Certificate Services
Certificate added: C=GB, S=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=Comodo CA Limited, CN=Secure Certificate Services
Certificate added: C=GB, S=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=Comodo CA Limited, CN=Trusted Certificate Services
Certificate added: O="Cybertrust, Inc", CN=Cybertrust Global Root
Certificate added: C=DE, O=D-Trust GmbH, CN=D-TRUST Root Class 3 CA 2 2009
Certificate added: C=DE, O=D-Trust GmbH, CN=D-TRUST Root Class 3 CA 2 EV 2009
Certificate added: C=US, O=Digital Signature Trust, OU=DST ACES, CN=DST ACES CA X6
Certificate added: O=Digital Signature Trust Co., CN=DST Root CA X3
Certificate added: C=DE, O=Deutsche Telekom AG, OU=T-TeleSec Trust Center, CN=Deutsche Telekom Root CA 2
Certificate added: C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, OU=www.digicert.com, CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root CA
Certificate added: C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, OU=www.digicert.com, CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root G2
Certificate added: C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, OU=www.digicert.com, CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root G3
Certificate added: C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, OU=www.digicert.com, CN=DigiCert Global Root CA
Certificate added: C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, OU=www.digicert.com, CN=DigiCert Global Root G2
Certificate added: C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, OU=www.digicert.com, CN=DigiCert Global Root G3
Certificate added: C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, OU=www.digicert.com, CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
Certificate added: C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, OU=www.digicert.com, CN=DigiCert Trusted Root G4
Certificate added: C=TR, L=Ankara, O=E-Tuğra EBG Bilişim Teknolojileri ve Hizmetleri A.Ş., OU=E-Tugra Sertifikasyon Merkezi, CN=E-Tugra Certification Authority
Certificate added: C=ES, O=Agencia Catalana de Certificacio (NIF Q-0801176-I), OU=Serveis Publics de Certificacio, OU=Vegeu https://www.catcert.net/verarrel (c)03, OU=Jerarquia Entitats de Certificacio Catalanes, CN=EC-ACC
Certificate added: C=EE, O=AS Sertifitseerimiskeskus, CN=EE Certification Centre Root CA, E=pki@sk.ee
Certificate added: O=Entrust.net, OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.), OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited, CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)
Certificate added: C=US, O="Entrust, Inc.", OU=www.entrust.net/CPS is incorporated by reference, OU="(c) 2006 Entrust, Inc.", CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority
Certificate added: C=US, O="Entrust, Inc.", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, OU="(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - EC1
Certificate added: C=US, O="Entrust, Inc.", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, OU="(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2
Certificate added: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Global CA
Certificate added: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Global CA 2
Certificate added: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority
Certificate added: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., OU=(c) 2007 GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only, CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G2
Certificate added: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., OU=(c) 2008 GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only, CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G3
Certificate added: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Universal CA
Certificate added: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Universal CA 2
Certificate added: OU=GlobalSign ECC Root CA - R4, O=GlobalSign, CN=GlobalSign
Certificate added: OU=GlobalSign ECC Root CA - R5, O=GlobalSign, CN=GlobalSign
Certificate added: C=BE, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, OU=Root CA, CN=GlobalSign Root CA
Certificate added: OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O=GlobalSign, CN=GlobalSign
Certificate added: OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3, O=GlobalSign, CN=GlobalSign
Certificate added: C=EU, L=Madrid (see current address at www.camerfirma.com/address), OID.2.5.4.5=A82743287, O=AC Camerfirma S.A., CN=Global Chambersign Root - 2008
Certificate added: C=US, O="The Go Daddy Group, Inc.", OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
Certificate added: C=US, S=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.", CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
Certificate added: C=GR, L=Athens, O=Hellenic Academic and Research Institutions Cert. Authority, CN=Hellenic Academic and Research Institutions ECC RootCA 2015
Certificate added: C=GR, O=Hellenic Academic and Research Institutions Cert. Authority, CN=Hellenic Academic and Research Institutions RootCA 2011
Certificate added: C=GR, L=Athens, O=Hellenic Academic and Research Institutions Cert. Authority, CN=Hellenic Academic and Research Institutions RootCA 2015
Certificate added: C=HK, O=Hongkong Post, CN=Hongkong Post Root CA 1
Certificate added: C=US, O=Internet Security Research Group, CN=ISRG Root X1
Certificate added: C=US, O=IdenTrust, CN=IdenTrust Commercial Root CA 1
Certificate added: C=US, O=IdenTrust, CN=IdenTrust Public Sector Root CA 1
Certificate added: C=ES, O=IZENPE S.A., CN=Izenpe.com
Certificate added: C=HU, L=Budapest, O=Microsec Ltd., OU=e-Szigno CA, CN=Microsec e-Szigno Root CA
Certificate added: C=HU, L=Budapest, O=Microsec Ltd., CN=Microsec e-Szigno Root CA 2009, E=info@e-szigno.hu
Certificate added: C=HU, L=Budapest, O=NetLock Kft., OU=Tanúsítványkiadók (Certification Services), CN=NetLock Arany (Class Gold) Főtanúsítvány
Certificate added: C=US, O=Network Solutions L.L.C., CN=Network Solutions Certificate Authority
Certificate added: C=CH, O=WISeKey, OU=Copyright (c) 2005, OU=OISTE Foundation Endorsed, CN=OISTE WISeKey Global Root GA CA
Certificate added: C=CH, O=WISeKey, OU=OISTE Foundation Endorsed, CN=OISTE WISeKey Global Root GB CA
Certificate added: C=FR, O=OpenTrust, CN=OpenTrust Root CA G1
Certificate added: C=FR, O=OpenTrust, CN=OpenTrust Root CA G2
Certificate added: C=FR, O=OpenTrust, CN=OpenTrust Root CA G3
Certificate added: E=contacto@procert.net.ve, L=Chacao, S=Miranda, OU=Proveedor de Certificados PROCERT, O=Sistema Nacional de Certificacion Electronica, C=VE, CN=PSCProcert
Certificate added: C=BM, O=QuoVadis Limited, OU=Root Certification Authority, CN=QuoVadis Root Certification Authority
Certificate added: C=BM, O=QuoVadis Limited, CN=QuoVadis Root CA 1 G3
Certificate added: C=BM, O=QuoVadis Limited, CN=QuoVadis Root CA 2
Certificate added: C=BM, O=QuoVadis Limited, CN=QuoVadis Root CA 2 G3
Certificate added: C=BM, O=QuoVadis Limited, CN=QuoVadis Root CA 3
Certificate added: C=BM, O=QuoVadis Limited, CN=QuoVadis Root CA 3 G3
Certificate added: O=RSA Security Inc, OU=RSA Security 2048 V3
Certificate added: C=ES, O=Generalitat Valenciana, OU=PKIGVA, CN=Root CA Generalitat Valenciana
Certificate added: C=PL, O=Krajowa Izba Rozliczeniowa S.A., CN=SZAFIR ROOT CA2
Certificate added: C=JP, O="Japan Certification Services, Inc.", CN=SecureSign RootCA11
Certificate added: C=US, O=SecureTrust Corporation, CN=SecureTrust CA
Certificate added: C=US, O=SecureTrust Corporation, CN=Secure Global CA
Certificate added: C=JP, O="SECOM Trust Systems CO.,LTD.", OU=Security Communication EV RootCA1
Certificate added: C=JP, O="SECOM Trust Systems CO.,LTD.", OU=Security Communication RootCA2
Certificate added: C=JP, O=SECOM Trust.net, OU=Security Communication RootCA1
Certificate added: C=FI, O=Sonera, CN=Sonera Class2 CA
Certificate added: C=NL, O=Staat der Nederlanden, CN=Staat der Nederlanden EV Root CA
Certificate added: C=NL, O=Staat der Nederlanden, CN=Staat der Nederlanden Root CA - G2
Certificate added: C=NL, O=Staat der Nederlanden, CN=Staat der Nederlanden Root CA - G3
Certificate added: C=US, O="Starfield Technologies, Inc.", OU=Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority
Certificate added: C=US, S=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O="Starfield Technologies, Inc.", CN=Starfield Root Certificate Authority - G2
Certificate added: C=US, S=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O="Starfield Technologies, Inc.", CN=Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2
Certificate added: C=IL, O=StartCom Ltd., OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing, CN=StartCom Certification Authority
Certificate added: C=IL, O=StartCom Ltd., OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing, CN=StartCom Certification Authority
Certificate added: C=IL, O=StartCom Ltd., CN=StartCom Certification Authority G2
Certificate added: C=CH, O=SwissSign AG, CN=SwissSign Gold CA - G2
Certificate added: C=CH, O=SwissSign AG, CN=SwissSign Silver CA - G2
Certificate added: C=ch, O=Swisscom, OU=Digital Certificate Services, CN=Swisscom Root CA 1
Certificate added: C=ch, O=Swisscom, OU=Digital Certificate Services, CN=Swisscom Root CA 2
Certificate added: C=ch, O=Swisscom, OU=Digital Certificate Services, CN=Swisscom Root EV CA 2
Certificate added: C=DE, O=T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH, OU=T-Systems Trust Center, CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 2
Certificate added: C=DE, O=T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH, OU=T-Systems Trust Center, CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 3
Certificate added: CN=TÜRKTRUST Elektronik Sertifika Hizmet Sağlayıcısı, C=TR, L=Ankara, O=TÜRKTRUST Bilgi İletişim ve Bilişim Güvenliği Hizmetleri A.Ş. (c) Aralık 2007
Certificate added: C=TW, O=TAIWAN-CA, OU=Root CA, CN=TWCA Global Root CA
Certificate added: C=TW, O=TAIWAN-CA, OU=Root CA, CN=TWCA Root Certification Authority
Certificate added: C=TW, O=Government Root Certification Authority
Certificate added: O=TeliaSonera, CN=TeliaSonera Root CA v1
Certificate added: C=GB, O=Trustis Limited, OU=Trustis FPS Root CA
Certificate added: C=TR, L=Gebze - Kocaeli, O=Türkiye Bilimsel ve Teknolojik Araştırma Kurumu - TÜBİTAK, OU=Ulusal Elektronik ve Kriptoloji Araştırma Enstitüsü - UEKAE, OU=Kamu Sertifikasyon Merkezi, CN=TÜBİTAK UEKAE Kök Sertifika Hizmet Sağlayıcısı - Sürüm 3
Certificate added: C=TR, L=Ankara, O=TÜRKTRUST Bilgi İletişim ve Bilişim Güvenliği Hizmetleri A.Ş., CN=TÜRKTRUST Elektronik Sertifika Hizmet Sağlayıcısı H5
Certificate added: C=TR, L=Ankara, O=TÜRKTRUST Bilgi İletişim ve Bilişim Güvenliği Hizmetleri A.Ş., CN=TÜRKTRUST Elektronik Sertifika Hizmet Sağlayıcısı H6
Certificate added: C=US, S=New Jersey, L=Jersey City, O=The USERTRUST Network, CN=USERTrust ECC Certification Authority
Certificate added: C=US, S=New Jersey, L=Jersey City, O=The USERTRUST Network, CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
Certificate added: C=US, S=UT, L=Salt Lake City, O=The USERTRUST Network, OU=http://www.usertrust.com, CN=UTN-USERFirst-Hardware
Certificate added: C=US, O="VeriSign, Inc.", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 2007 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G4
Certificate added: C=US, O="VeriSign, Inc.", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
Certificate added: C=US, O="VeriSign, Inc.", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 2008 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN=VeriSign Universal Root Certification Authority
Certificate added: C=US, O="VeriSign, Inc.", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3
Certificate added: C=US, O=VISA, OU=Visa International Service Association, CN=Visa eCommerce Root
Certificate added: C=US, O=Wells Fargo WellsSecure, OU=Wells Fargo Bank NA, CN=WellsSecure Public Root Certificate Authority
Certificate added: C=CN, O=WoSign CA Limited, CN=Certification Authority of WoSign
Certificate added: C=CN, O=WoSign CA Limited, CN=CA 沃通根证书
Certificate added: C=US, OU=www.xrampsecurity.com, O=XRamp Security Services Inc, CN=XRamp Global Certification Authority
Certificate added: C=RO, O=certSIGN, OU=certSIGN ROOT CA
Certificate added: C=TW, O="Chunghwa Telecom Co., Ltd.", OU=ePKI Root Certification Authority
Certificate added: C=US, O="thawte, Inc.", OU=Certification Services Division, OU="(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN=thawte Primary Root CA
Certificate added: C=US, O="thawte, Inc.", OU="(c) 2007 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN=thawte Primary Root CA - G2
Certificate added: C=US, O="thawte, Inc.", OU=Certification Services Division, OU="(c) 2008 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN=thawte Primary Root CA - G3
Certificate added: O=Root CA, OU=http://www.cacert.org, CN=CA Cert Signing Authority, E=support@cacert.org
Certificate added: O=CAcert Inc., OU=http://www.CAcert.org, CN=CAcert Class 3 Root
157 new root certificates were added to your trust store.
Import process completed.
(3/4) installing keepass                           [######################] 100%
Optional dependencies for keepass
```

I am interested in for what these certificates and who maintains them. There over problem is that I cannot find an answer how does `pacman` package signing verification works and is it vulnerable to MITM attacks when running package list syncing.

Answer (score 2):

Linux has a list of trusted root CA in `/etc/ssl/certs` or similar locations. Various applications (like browsers) or programming languages (like Java) come with their own CA store while others use the systems CA store. This *"Synchronize local certs with certs from local Linux trust store."* probably just means that Mono imports the system certificates into its own CA store so that Mono applications will trust the same certificates as other applications on the system.

As to where these system certificates come from and who maintains these see the package information for [ca-certificates](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/any/ca-certificates/) in Arch Linux but it looks like that it trusts the same CA Mozilla (i.e. Firefox) trusts.